# Local fonts with Next.js and Styled Components

Tags: reactjs, next.js, styled-components

I want to add an local font to the project.
I'm using `next.js` and `globalStyles` from `styled-components`.

Here is what I've done so far

```
import regularFont from "../public/fonts/IRANYekanRegular.ttf";

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle<{ lang?: Languages_type | string }>`
@font-face {
  font-family: "ir";
  src: local("ir"), url(${regularFont}) format("truetype");
}     
 
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  font-family:"ir ";
}

`;
```

But with the above code it throws and error that says

> ./public/fonts/IRANYekanRegular.ttf Module parse failed: Unexpected
> character '' (1:0) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this
> file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.
> See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders (Source code omitted for
> this binary file)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Next.js and React applications you can access `public` files with the absolute route.

So, in your CSS you can do something like:

```js
const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle<{ lang?: Languages_type | string }>`
@font-face {
  font-family: "ir";
  src: local("ir"), url('/fonts/IRANYekanRegular.ttf') format("truetype");
}     
 
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  font-family:"ir";
}

`;
```

Notice 2 things:

- I'm not importing the file
- I'm using the route after public

Not sure if we can use codesanbox for next, so,

- I created on Repo (you can check the commits): https://github.com/joseglego/font-test - The definition is: https://github.com/joseglego/font-test/blob/main/pages/index.js
- Deploy on netlify: https://eager-ardinghelli-b3d680.netlify.app/

Comment: Error is gone but font does not apply. Also absolute route in IDE's auto complete suggests directories from the root, not public. Any idea?

Comment: Let me try something!

Comment: You won't believe it! but you have in the body/use:   ```font-family:"it "```; (There is one blank space and in the definition you only have   ```font-family: "ir";```

Comment: I removed it and still not applying. Maybe i should add a link to `Head` in `_document` file, Don't you think?

Comment: I updated my answer with one github example (with the commits) and with the netlify server running :) can you check it?

Comment: Yeah, let me take a look.